# How to spread each field to a line in a file (with awk or cut, maybe?)

Tags: unix, osx-yosemite

I have a file in the following format:

```
'word', 'word', 'word'
'word', 'word', 'word'
'word', 'word', 'word', 'word', 'word'
'word'
```

How can I split the lines at `,` and print the following:

```
'word'
'word'
'word'
'word'
...
```

(note: OS X Yosemite)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`tr`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_%28Unix%29) to replace ',' with '\n'

```
cat somefile | tr ',' '\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace the `,` with a new line.

```
 sed 's/, /\n/g' file
```